# Getting entire row before the last row in a table

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `table`, which firsts loads data from a database.
The `table` has an add row functionality, which is in the tfoot and is the last `tr`.
I want to be able to clone the previous row.
How can I do this ?

```
$row = $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr')  /*but this does not work.*/

var
                $table = $(this).closest('table'),
                $row = $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr'),
                $newRow = $row.clone();
                $table.append($('table.order-list').append($newRow));
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it, it is

```
    var


       len = $('#tblId tr').length,
                    $row = $('#tblId tr').eq(len - 2),
$newRow = $row.clone();
```